# Inverse function

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, source-layout

Wouldn't it be neat if programming functions could be inverted, just like the mathematical function they implement?

Write a function (or program) that takes one input `x` in any form, that outputs `ln(x)`.
When the bytes of the program are reordered/reversed so that the first byte now is the last byte, it should take one input `x` in any form and output `e^x` instead.

- Your answer must have at least 3 correct significant figures.
- Approximations are fine, as long as they have at least 3 correct significant figures.
- Your code must be in the same programming language both forwards and backwards.

Let's say this program implements `ln(x)`:

```
abc你好
```

Then this program has to implement `e^x`:

```
\xBD\xA5\xE5\xA0\xBD\xE4cba
```

Gold star if you use a language without float support.

This is a weird form of code-golf, so the shortest program wins.

Comment: "Wouldn't it be neat if programming functions could be inverted, just like the mathematical function they implement?" Some languages (e.g. J and Mathematica) can actually do this for some functions.

Comment: Additionally, K2 could approximate an inverse for an arbitrary monadic  pure function via its "function inverse" overload of dyadic and triadic `?`, which used the secant method.

Comment: "at least 3 correct significant figures" - over what range?

Comment: I realize it's far too late now, but I think this would have been a really nice challenge had comments been disallowed.

Comment: I actually thought of that when I came up with this challenge @AlexA. but forgot about it while writing the post :P Also that would've made "normal" languages like java, c++ etc basically impossible.

Comment: @TLW a big enough range, say up to 10k? I want you to have to handle printing floats, and a 32bit int should be enough for storage.

Answer (score 75):

### Haskell, 11 bytes

```
f=log
pxe=f
```

and in reverse order:

```
f=exp
gol=f
```

This works without the "comment" trick. Instead each version defines an additional, but unused function (`pxe`/ `gol`).

Comment: +1 for `gol=f`.

Comment: This is also a valid solution in Julia.

Answer (score 42):

## APL, 3 bytes

```
*⊣⍟
```

This is a function train. Monadic `*`  returns `e^x`, monadic `⍟` returns `ln(x)`. `⊣` is a dyadic function that returns its left argument. Thus, `*⊣⍟` is equivalent to just `*`, and the reverse `⍟⊣*` is equivalent to just `⍟`.

Answer (score 22):

### Jelly, <s>5</s> 4 bytes

Yay, my first Jelly answer. :) Input is via command-line argument.

Jelly [has its own code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/docs/code-page.md) so each character is one byte.

```
eÆÆl
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=ZcOGw4Zs&input=&args=NQ)

Reversed:

```
lÆÆe
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=bMOGw4Zl&input=&args=NQ)

#### Explanation

The `Æ` on its own is an unrecognised token, so it acts the same as a linefeed. That means in either case the main link is only `Æl` or `Æe` which is the 2-character built-in for `exp()` or `ln()` and is by default performed on the first command-line argument.

Answer (score 9):

### Javascript, 18 bytes

```
Math.log//pxe.htaM
```

Comment: Don't you need a return() or console.log() around it?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 It evaluates to a function, which should be permissible.

Comment: `Math.ln||pxe.htaM` will probably also work.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Thanks, that helped me spot the error in my answer!

Comment: @Neil I hadn't even noticed that

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ That's not how it works. Try assigning it to a function `f`: `f=Math.log//pxe.htaM`, then calling it with input.

Answer (score 7):

### Seriously, 5 bytes

```
,_.e,
```

Input, ln, output, then exp on an empty stack (does nothing), and input (does nothing since input is exhausted). [Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LF8uZSw&input=Mi43MTgyODE4Mjg0NTkwNDUyMzUzNjAyODc0NzEzNTI2NjI0OTc3NTcyNDcwOTM2OTk5NQ)

Reversed:

```
,e._,
```

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LGUuXyw&input=MQ)

Comment: The language name is hilarious

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 19 bytes

```
1&#@pxE+0&0+Log@#&1
```

Reversed:

```
1&#@goL+0&0+Exp@#&1
```

This was interesting to golf! Mathematica has *no* line comments / implicit string endings, so I couldn't take the simple route. Instead, I used the fact that `0 + x == x`, `0 x == 0`, and that `1 x == x`, no matter what `x` is! Testing:

```
In[1]:= (1&#@pxE+0&0+Log@#&1)[x]

Out[1]= Log[x]

In[2]:= (1&#@goL+0&0+Exp@#&1)[x]

         x
Out[2]= E
```

Answer (score 5):

## Julia, 7 bytes

```
log#pxe
```

This is an anonymous function. Assign it to a variable to call it. Evaluates to builtins `log` or `exp` plus a comment.

Comment: Same answer works for R

Answer (score 4):

## Python2, 73 bytes

io: stdin/stdout

```
from math import*;print log(input())#))(tupni(pxe tnirp;*tropmi htam morf
```

inverse:

```
from math import*;print exp(input())#))(tupni(gol tnirp;*tropmi htam morf
```

Comment: You can shave 10 characters off by using `__import__("math").` instead of

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, 11 bytes

```
rdmle#eemdr
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=rdmle%23eemdr&input=5)

Reversed:

```
rdmee#elmdr
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=rdmee%23elmdr&input=5)

Basically the same comment-trick as the OP's Python answer. `e#` starts a comment. `rd` reads the input and `ml` or `me` computes the logarithm or exponential.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 3 bytes

```
*₁≡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wX@tRU@OjzoX//0cb6hjpGOmZG1oYWYCwiamlgYmpjnEsAA)

Initially, I had hoped to use `~*`, but although `*~` computes `e^x` and successfully ignores the trailing tilde, `~*` fails for all integer inputs and hits a float overflow on most non-integer inputs.

Forwards:

```
       The output
  ≡    is
*₁     the natural logarithm of
       the input.
```

Backwards:

```
       The output is
  *    Euler's number to the power of
       the input
≡      passed through the identity predicate
 ₁     with an extraneous subscript.
```

This uses the identity predicate because, although trailing tildes are tolerated, leading subscripts are not. (If they were, the Brachylog answer would be `*₁` alone, which is just the normal builtin for natural log.)

Answer (score 2):

## Vitsy, 5 bytes

This is a program that exits on an error.

```
EL^rE
E   E  Push java.lang.Math.E
 L     Push log_(top) (input) (ln(input))
  ^    Push (top)^(input)  (e^(input))
   r   Reverse the stack
```

This program exits on an error with ln(input) on the stack.

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=RUxOXkU&input=&args=Mi43MTgyODE4Mjg0NTkwNDUyMzUzNjAyODc0NzEzNTI2NjI0OTc3NTcyNDcwOTM2OTk5NQ) (note that I have put `N` to have visible output)

Then it's inverse:

```
Er^LE
```

This program exits on an error with e^(input) on the stack.

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=RXJeTkxF&input=&args=MQ)

Answer (score 2):

## Fuzzy Octo Guacamole, 7 bytes

<sub>non-competing, FOG is newer than the challenge</sub>

```
EZO@pZE
```

This is the equivalent of a function in FOG.  It assumes the input is on the stack. This can be assigned to a function by the code `"EZO@pZE""f"o`, where `f` is any single-char name you want to assign.  Then use it like any other command. Example: `"EZO@pZE"'f'o^f`.

Explanation:

```
EZO@pZE
E       # Push E (2.718....)
 Z      # Reverse stack (it is now [e, input])
  O     # log(x, y) which is ln(input)
   @    # Exit. (implicit output) Nothing after this gets run.
    p   # x^y (power function)
     Z  # Reverse stack
      E # Push E.
```

Reversed:

```
EZp@OZE
E       # Push E (2.718....)
 Z      # Reverse stack (it is now [e, input])
  O     # x^y (power function)
   @    # Exit. (implicit output) Nothing after this gets run.
    p   # log(x, y) which is ln(input)
     Z  # Reverse stack
      E # Push E.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Matl, 5 bytes

```
Yl%eZ
```

`Yl`: log
`Ze`: exp
`%`: comment

Comment: Thanks to Dennis, there's an [online compiler for MATL](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WWwlZVo&input=MTA)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 12 bytes

Finds `ln(input())`

```
.lQ) " Q1n.^
```

Finds `e^input()`

```
^.n1Q " )Ql.
```

Spaces stop implicit printing of strings, each version calculates it then creates a string with the remaining characters.

[`ln(x)` mode here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.lQ%29+%22+Q1n.%5E&input=2&debug=0)

[`e^x` mode here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%5E.n1Q+%22+%29Ql.&input=1&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## , 8 chars / 10 bytes

```
МŬï//ïŦМ
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=true&input=1&code=%D0%9C%C5%AC%C3%AF%2F%2F%C3%AF%C5%A6%D0%9C)</kbd><kbd>[Try reverse here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=true&input=1&code=%D0%9C%C5%A6%C3%AF%2F%2F%C3%AF%C5%AC%D0%9C)</kbd>

Just 2 builtins separated by a comment.

Answer (score 1):

## Jolf, 9 bytes

Program 1: `exp` of input

```
amoj"jOma
a         print
 moj      e^j
    "jOma  the rest of the line is captured as a string; implicit printing is restricted.
```

Program 2: `ln` of input

```
amOj"joma
a         print
 mOj      ln(j)
    "joma  the rest of the line is captured as a string; implicit printing is restricted.
```

Bonus points for being a case-insensitive palindrome? [Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=YW1vaiJqT21h)

Answer (score 1):

## J, 8 bytes

The natural logarithm is `^.`, and exponential `^`. The problem is, `.` can only modify a valid verb, otherwise, a spelling error will occur. Thus, we can't use the left argument trick in the APL answer, becuase `^.[^` would cause an error when reversed, as `^[.^` creates an invalid verb. So, we must use comments; but `NB.` is so long :( Fortunately, they both end with `.`, so&ldots; there's that.

Logarithm:

```
^.NB.BN^
```

Exponential:

```
^NB.BN.^
```

You can enter them for yourself [online](http://tryj.tk/)!

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 9 bytes

```
i'lA@Ae'i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z9TPcfRwTFVPfP/fwA)

An ungodly uninteresting program. `@` insures termination of the implied entry point at the left, everything after is unexecuted. I tried really hard to re-use the `'` or `A` instructions, but to no avail, even at larger program sizes. The required explicit entry point for multi-line programs essentially precludes it.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>198</s> <s>182</s> 30 bytes

```
d->Math.log(d)//)d(pxe.htaM<-d
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##NY6xEoIwEER7v@LKpCBUVqh/AA2lY3EmEYIhyZCD0XH49hgVm5vb23m7N@CChQ/aDeqepMUYoUbjXjsA40hPN5Qamo8EUH6@Wg2SbYviVb6vXy@PSEhGQgMOjkkVpxqpF9Z3TPGy5IqFhxY9YX0oVKr@UMhJGdrYxRsFY@5nLU3GdecL8l93@4ykR@FnEiE7ZB1zQrI9335Y0xs)

and reversed:

```
d->Math.exp(d)//)d(gol.htaM<-d
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##NY6xEoIwEER7v@LKpCBUVqh/AA2lY3EmEYIhyZCD0XH49hgVm5vb23m7N@CChQ/aDeqepMUYoUbjXjsA40hPN5Qamo8EUH6@Wg2SbYviVb6vXy@PSEhGQgMOjkkVpxqpF/oRmOJlyRXrvBU9YX0oVKr@UMhJGdrYxRsFY@5nLU3GdecL8l93@4ykR@FnEiE7ZB1zQrI9335Y0xs)

Uses the comment trick (`//`) with built-ins for `Math.log` and `Math.exp`.